# Different composer.json files for production and staging/development

Tags: git, composer-php

Scenario:

I have an existing live site that loads in composer dependencies via several GIT repositories on `dev-master`.

A new feature request comes in from the client and before I merge it from develop into master I need to deploy the new (unfinished) feature to a staging environment to get OK from the client before pushing live (I may need to show the client an early version of the new feature, not at all ready for master).

I usually deploy stuff via capistrano (not that it makes any difference I guess).

I can't use `require-dev` for the new code as it's likely an existing plugin that needs to be refactored.

Ideally I'd be able to use `dev-develop` for the plugin on the staging/development environment and `dev-master` for the live environment, but it's not possible to have the same repository twice in the same composer.json file.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can just have two different versions of the composer.json on different git branches. While developing new feature, do it in the separate branch, called `my-feature` and deploy it to the dev environment to show.

Comment: @Ostrovski yeah, though about that, but it doesn't really help... I need to be able to deploy to production and staging at the same time. I don't want to merge in develop into master and then have to go in manually to change the composer.json file.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution is to use environmental variables.

I have 2 `composer.json` files (and also 2 `composer.lock` files). The 2nd I named `composer-dev.json` (this will subsequently generate a lock filed named `composer-dev.lock`).

In my capistrano deploy config for the stage server I added

```
set :default_env, {
    'COMPOSER' => 'composer-dev.json'
}
```

I can [define the environmental variable on the fly](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer) on my local machine like so:

```
$ COMPOSER=composer-dev.json composer update
```

which generates the `composer-dev.lock` file I can then deploy to the staging server.

Of course I could have configured the environment on the staging server, it just seems easier to do it in my capistrano config.

Comment: Hi, I am very new to web development and deploying, is it possible to provide a resource about controlling different composer.json files from environment variables? I am only making a very small test-task which I want to deploy and I need a very very slightly different composer file so learning capistrano or phing seems difficult for that only

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. You saved my day Richard! Have a nice day!