# how to handle different composer configurations in the same project?

Tags: composer-php

Since a few days, I am working 50% from home and 50% from my company.

When I work from my company, I have to use an internal private mirror because of the firewall policy that don't allow direct outgoing requests, thus I have the following configuration lines in my `composer.json`. This is working fine.

```
  "repositories": {
    "nexus": {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https:/my-company.com/repository/composer"
    },
    "packagist": false
  },
  "config": {
    "secure-http": false,
    "cafile": "cacert-custom.pem"
  },
```

When I work from home, I have a direct internet access and I don't have access to this private mirror. Thus, when I run composer from home, I don't want those lines to be used.

The rest of the `composer.json` file is the same.

I want to be able with the same base code to get composer working from both home or work.

How can I manage that ?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35574562/1632809).

I make use of the `COMPOSER` environment variable which I set to `composer.json` or `composer-company.json`

Then, I have 2 dependencies files `composer.json` and `composer-company.json`.

The `composer.json` does not wear the private repo lines whereas the `composer-company.json` has these special lines.

[See that official doc.](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer)